# Difference in files on windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have a very peculiar problem. I need to send some signed XML to a web service. I've implemented the signing, that takes the XML, signs it and then sends it to the service. It all worked ok on my pc, but when I deployed the application on my server, I started getting a response, that the signature is wrong.

I've tried copying the file to my pc and sending it again, and it worked. Am I right in thinking that the OS could be storing files in a different format and that that might be responsible for the error? I tried installing the same version of java on my pc and my server and I've tried to save files on a FAT32 partition on my pc, but nothing changed.

I save the file using a Transformer:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty("standalone", "no");
result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
```

and I read the file into a Data handler:

```
SendDocument sendDocument = new SendDocument();
sendDocument.setValue(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(new FileInputStream(Util.signed(tempFolder, toSend)), "application/octet-stream")));
myService.sendDocument(sendDocument);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Nevermind, there were some other problems with my signature time, I solved them and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the encoding.

On your server try to run with `-D` parameter and setting the `file.encoding` property. (`java -Dfile.encoding=Something` ...)